# NavigationBar Buttons Click Area not working properly (Image is not clickable)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar

Xcode 11.4 - iOS 13.4

Navigation bar UIBarButton items are not working as expected. (I used storyboard for buttons - no code written)

It was working just fine after I updated Xcode. Now it is not working.

Only Green area can be touched. Images **can not.** I also checked Screen Debugger and everything is seems correct.

[image: Image from Screen Debugger]

There is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58134631/ios-13-uibarbuttonitem-not-clickable-and-overlapping-uinavigationbars-when-using) like this but for search bar and push. However, answers not solving my problem.

If you can not figure out how the hell is not working?

You can also check [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqMbO.gif) for a similar situation from another stack overflow question.

It is not the same, (no push, or search bar) but "not clickable images" are the same.

Comment: Please stabilise the IBAction  .touchUpInside

Comment: How did you add your image? Did you drag a `UIBarButtonItem` into place and set its Image? Or something else...

Comment: @DonMag, I drag button then set its image, over storyboard.

Comment: @SarveshSingh I did, it is connected as IBAction in viewcontroller. No problem here. It was working just fine, After I update Xcode no bar item work. Toolbar is same too.

Comment: @Clown - I'm not experiencing this... Try it in a new project and see if you get the same problem.

Comment: @Clown can you share your code?

Comment: @SarveshSingh No code has written, It generated from Storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are possible 2 solutions that I found so far

1) Downgrade Xcode to 11.3.1 from 
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=xcode

2) This UIButton extension breaks all the UIBarButtons in Navigation Bar and also in Tool Bar. This is just for my case. You may have same override func that may break.

```
extension UIButton{
    open override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        return self.bounds.contains(point) ? self : nil
    }
}
```